# numpy.logical_and versus multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean, boolean-operations

Given three `numpy` arrays `a`, `b`, and `c` (EDIT: of the same shape/size), it seems that for non-complex numbers

```
a * b * c != 0  # test element-wise whether all are non-zero
```

gives the same result as:

```
np.logical_and(a, np.logical_and(b, c))
```

Is there a hidden pitfall in the first version? Is there even a simpler way to test this?

Comment: [Here's one of several pitfalls.](http://ideone.com/L0Z0Xu)

Comment: This works for me in Python 2.7 and 3.4. I guess the example comes from a (very?) old Python version with fixed integer representation?

Comment: No, it works like that in the very most recent versions of Python. You most likely ran your tests with Python built-in integers instead of NumPy data types.

Comment: `a = b = c = numpy.array([2**16]); a * b * c != 0` works just fine, as I expect and not as shown in the link, in any of my Python's. So where is the pitfall? And what are the others?

Comment: Try it with `numpy.array([2**24])`, then. Maybe it's defaulting to 64-bit ints for you. The pitfall here is that NumPy integers are fixed-width, wrapping on overflow, unlike Python's overflow-free bignums. You'll run into similar problems with floating-point data due to NaNs and underflow; for example, `a = b = numpy.array([numpy.nan])` and `c = numpy.array([0.0])`.

Answer (score 4):

Given `b` and `c` holding real numbers, `np.logical_and(b, c)` would esentially involve under-the-hood conversion to boolean numbers.

Can we do the conversion upfront? If so, would that help?

Now, the stated operation of checking if **`ALL`** corresponding elements are non-zeros would be equivalent to checking if the boolean-not of **`ANY`** of the corresponding elements are zeros, i.e.

`~((a == 0) + (b==0) + (c==0)`

OR

`~((a == 0) | (b==0) | (c==0))`

Also, this would involve upfront conversion to boolean after comparison with `zero`, so that might help with performance. Here's the runtime numbers involved -

**Case #1:**

```
In [10]: # Setup inputs
    ...: M, N = 100, 100
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: c = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: 

In [11]: %timeit np.logical_and(a, np.logical_and(b, c))
    ...: %timeit a * b * c != 0
    ...: %timeit ~((a == 0) + (b==0) + (c==0))
    ...: %timeit ~((a == 0) | (b==0) | (c==0))
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 96.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.2 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.6 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 51.5 µs per loop
```

**Case #2:**

```
In [12]: # Setup inputs
    ...: M, N = 1000, 1000
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: c = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: 

In [13]: %timeit np.logical_and(a, np.logical_and(b, c))
    ...: %timeit a * b * c != 0
    ...: %timeit ~((a == 0) + (b==0) + (c==0))
    ...: %timeit ~((a == 0) | (b==0) | (c==0))
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.29 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 9.2 ms per loop
```

**Case #3:**

```
In [14]: # Setup inputs
    ...: M, N = 5000, 5000
    ...: a = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: b = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: c = np.random.randint(0,5,(M,N))
    ...: 

In [15]: %timeit np.logical_and(a, np.logical_and(b, c))
    ...: %timeit a * b * c != 0
    ...: %timeit ~((a == 0) + (b==0) + (c==0))
    ...: %timeit ~((a == 0) | (b==0) | (c==0))
    ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 294 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 694 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 268 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 268 ms per loop
```

Seems like there is a good percentage of benefit with the `comparison to zero approach`!

Answer (score 4):

Some observations:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
​
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100000)
b = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100000)
c = np.random.randint(0, 5, 100000)
​
method_one = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a, b), c)
%timeit np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a, b), c)
​
method_two = a*b*c != 0
%timeit a*b*c != 0
​
method_three = np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a.astype('bool'), b.astype('bool')), c.astype('bool'))
%timeit np.logical_and(np.logical_and(a.astype('bool'), b.astype('bool')), c.astype('bool'))
​
method_four = a.astype('bool') * b.astype('bool') * c.astype('bool')  != 0
%timeit a.astype('bool') * b.astype('bool') * c.astype('bool')  != 0


# verify all methods give equivalent results
all([
    np.all(method_one == method_two), 
    np.all(method_one == method_three),
    np.all(method_one == method_four)
    ]
   )
```

---

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 713 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 341 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 252 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 388 µs per loop

True
```

Some interpretations:

1. The speed of the `a*b*c != 0` method will depend on the `dtype` of the vectors, since multiplication is done first.  So if you've got floats or bigints or some other larger dtype, this step will take longer than for vectors of the same length that are boolean or small integers.  Coercing to a `bool` `dtype` speeds up this method.  If the vectors have *different* dtypes, things will be even slower.  Multiplying an integer array by a float array requires converting integers to floats, then coercing to boolean.  Not optimal.
2. For reasons I don't understand, **Prune**'s answer's statement that 
   *However, the logical test is faster* seems to be correct only when the input vectors are already boolean.  Perhaps the way in which coercion to boolean happens in the straight-up `logical_and()` method is slower than using `.asdtype('bool')`.
3. The fastest way to go seems to be (1) coerce inputs to boolean ahead of time and then (2) use `np.logical_and()`.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a short summary: `a * b * c != 0` can lead to an overflow or underflow. The alternative `~((a == 0) | (b == 0) | (c == 0))` seems to execute faster than any other implementation of the test.

Answer (score -1):

They are the same.  0 and None are **False**; any other value is **True**.  However, the logical test is faster.  If you have a lot of arrays in the list, consider using Python's **all** and **any** methods.

---

For example:

```
for value in [True, False, 0, 1, None, 7, 'a', [False, False, False]]:
    if value:
        print value, True
    else:
        print value, False
```

Output:

```
True True
False False
0 False
1 True
None False
7 True
a True
[False, False, False] True
```

Comment: "0 and None are False; any other value is True" - what? No. That's not how interpreting values as booleans works in Python.